# app crashes after deleting items of UICollectionView

Tags: swift, crash, uicollectionview, ios10, nsexception

[image]

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The values for the `selectedIndexPaths` property are correct. The user selects a bunch of items from the collection view, presses a delete button, is shown a confirm alert, than, after pressing yes, I attempt to 
remove the items from the collection view and update the data source correspondingly. Unfortunatelly, this doesn't work. Can anyone help?

UPDATE: @JAL here's the stacktrace:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full exception and backtrace?

Comment: Code please... That'd be helpful.